Read Xml value in oracle query
I need to extract the entire LinkSnapshot xml element from a list of these elements. The list is stored in a column named Links. I've tried the following but I'm getting an error that reads "19026. 00000 -  "EXTRACTVALUE can only retrieve value of leaf node""
 Extractvalue(xmltype(ss.links), '/List/LinkSnapshot') AS "Snapshot"

This is the xml
 <List>
   <LinkSnapshot application="App1" id="application1234" >
     <Attributes>
       <Map>
         <entry key="GenericAccount" value="false"/>       
       </Map>
     </Attributes>
   </LinkSnapshot>
 </List>

Is there a different command that I should use to extract the parent LinkSnapshot node as a whole?

Use XMLQUERY:
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         '//List/LinkSnapshot'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(ss.links)
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ) AS snapshot
FROM   table_name ss

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (links) AS
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '<List>
  <LinkSnapshot application="App1" id="application1234" >
    <Attributes>
      <Map>
        <entry key="GenericAccount" value="false"/>       
      </Map>
    </Attributes>
  </LinkSnapshot>
</List>' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



SNAPSHOT




<LinkSnapshot application="App1" id="application1234"><Attributes><Map><entry key="GenericAccount" value="false"/></Map></Attributes></LinkSnapshot>



fiddle

awesome. what if I wanted to add a where clause to only return the Linkshapshots that have an application equal to "App1"?

@MatthewTuman Use the XPATH //List/LinkSnapshot[@application="App1"] fiddle

@MatthewTuman, please don't forget to mark a working solution for you as Answer.
